# Should we use @Component annotation on the class just to document/indicate that it's a Bean?

Tags: spring

Even when we create the Beans in a Spring configuration class, I feel it is still useful to use @Component annotation on the class just to document/indicate that it's a Bean. Is it a good idea? Can there be any other issue that Spring will find the same bean defined in two different ways?

Comment: If someone inherits your component and is lazy in their component scan definition, your class may be registered as a bean in their particular application when they don't particularly want it to be -- or without them realizing it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is bad practice to create two beans from one class...

```
@Component
class SimpleComponent {
}

@Bean
public SimpleComponent simpleComponentBean(){
    new SimpleComponent();
}
```

By default if we use `@Component` spring creates bean with name of class, but starts with small letter `simpleComponent`, if we use `@Bean` it takes method name and create bean with name `simpleComponentBean` and we have duplicated beans...
If we have method name the same, as component class name, spring replace one of them and we can Inject unexpected bean.

PS: intellij idea enterprise - correct indicate about all beans.